# Mean first passage time (MFPT)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

I want to know the mean first passage time (MFPT) on a unit interval for two boundary conditions (please see attached figures a and b for your reference). This is in the context of the hydrodynamic dispersion of a particle.
In case a) the b.c switch from reflection to absorbing whereas in case b) the b.c is reflective. Can anyone help me to figure out the mean first passage time in this problem?

[image]